# cant make call to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token from angular

Tags: javascript, oauth

im trying get acsess token in my angular app but i get 400 error bad request.
from postman there is no problem and i get the token
this is in my js code.
i removed some info from my code here.

```
 return $http(
                    {
                        url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
                        method: "POST",
                        data : {
                            'grant_type':'password',
                            'client_id' : 'jD7TnTNigSlQouxCndKvmuhFoPrT8U5ScDsskdq7A',
                            'client_secret' : '6148471690',
                            'username' : 'test.com',
                            'password':'HPLCGE1rjFyERnD6CE'
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

                        }
                    });
```